# How convert the string of "06/22/2019 00:00:00" to a valid DateTime type in format of 2019/06/22 without the part of hour and minute and second

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am doing an asp.net mvc project and I need to convert the string of "06/22/2019 00:00:00" to a valid DateTime type in format of 2019/06/22 without the part of hour and minute and second

Comment: This kind of questions show up regularly. There is no variable of type DateTime without the Time part. It is how do you format the variable for display that matters here. So if you want to display only the date then _date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")_ and now you have a string to display that appears to an human being as a date only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **DateTime.ParseExact**, here is an example :

http://net-informations.com/q/faq/stringdate.html

Finally, it should look like this :

```
string s = "06/22/2019 00:00:00";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Debug.WriteLine(myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: Thank you. This code solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var dateString = "06/22/2019 00:00:00";
var datePart = dateString.Split(' ')[0];
var date = DateTime.Parse(datePart);
```

Though remember that `DateTime` will still have a default value for the time (12:00 AM), if you want the `Date` part only from the object, use `date.Date` which will return an instance with the default time (mentioned earlier).

Comment: Hello. Thank you. The code of (var datePart = dateString.Split(' ')[0])  will return me "06/22/2019" and in code of (var date = DateTime.Parse(datePart);)  will return me the error (
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime)

Comment: That's not true at all, here you can see for yourself https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Fc2C0

Answer (score 0):

You convert the string to a DateTime object and then to display just the date portion you can use ToShortDateString like this:

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.Parse( "06/22/2019 00:00:00") //presumably use a variable here instead.
var date = myDateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

How you want to display this can be done using the CultureInfo part as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

DateTime contains default `Time` even if you access `DateTime.Date`. You can achieve format of date by converting Date into string.

Something like,

```
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("06/22/2019 00:00:00", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string dateInFormat = $"{myDate.Year}/{myDate.Month}/{myDate.Day}";
```

POC : [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6KJXm5)